# calling registered javascript from primefaces datatable

Tags: jsf

i would like to have a datatable on different clients that is in sync.
theres a chat application here:
http://www.hascode.com/2013/08/creating-a-chat-application-using-java-ee-7-websockets-and-glassfish-4/

that basically does what i need.
each connected client gets all the messages via websocket.

so i created a primefaces dataTable (modified example from the primefaces page):

```
<h:form>  
<p:dataTable id="carTable" var="car" value="#{dtSortView.cars1}">  
<p:column headerText="Remove">  
                <h:outputText value="testing" />
                <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-close" title="testbotton" type="submit"/>
....
</h:form>
```

i register the function dosomething2() here:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#carTable').submit(function(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        dosomething2()
    });
});
```

and dosomething2 is defined like this:

```
function dosomething2(data) {
    alert('domsomething 22123');
}
```

but the alert never shows. why is it not called when i click the button?

what i want to achieve:
the user clicks a button in the table,
the line is removed immediately in the table and the table is updated,
all other connected clients get sent the same command via websocket (the websocket would be called from dosomething2)

i could be completely wrong with this idea, im open to suggestions.

Comment: Where is the function called `doSomething`? I don't see it in the question

Comment: uh, wrong name, its dosomething2....will edit.

Comment: But you still have `onclick="dosomething"`, what is that supposed to be pointing to?

Comment: you are right, got lost in my own code...tried to many things.  
lets remove onclick, code still wont call the alert but i guess it makes more sense

Comment: ok, after reading the other post which this is obviouls a duplicate:

this is the button in the generated html: 
    <button id="myform:carTable:2:j_idt18" name="myform:carTable:2:j_idt18" ....

but:  
$('#myform:carTable:2:j_idt18').submit(function(evt) {  

does not work to register the function

Comment: found a example from oracle that solves my problem beautifully:  
http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/HomeWebsocket/WebsocketHome.html#overview